# Excel: Sumproduct, calculating Dates into months

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column "A" has specific dates (Year, Month, Day) , I need a summary via
Sumproduct by months 1 - 12. And some other variables. I know I could add a column with "Month"
but I would like to avoid that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have valid dates in `A2:A100` then you can just use `MONTH` function in `SUMPRODUCT`, e.g. to count November dates you can use this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A2:A100)=11)*1)`

You can add other conditions as required

Answer (score -1):

Since you have not specified the next step so that  I've just assumed the task that is,

"How to calculate Month wise & Year total" using formulas like **SUMPRODUCT & SUMIFS.**

[image]

**Data Range is H304 to I309**.

**First two Formula are SUMPRODUCT in Cells I311 & I312**. [inspired from **Barry Houdini**]

=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(H$305:H$309)=1)*(I$305:I$309))

**NB:** Here 1 is Month Value.

I've created a **Bonus Formula to calculate  Year  Total in Cell I314** is,

{=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(H$305:H$309)={1,2})*(I$305:I$309))}

**Other Formula are SUMIFS with EOMONTH in Cells I316 & I317**.

=SUMIFS(I$305:I$309,H$305:$H$309,">="&$H$316,H$305:H$309,"<="&EOMONTH($H$316,0))

**NB:** Cell **H316 is Criteria**, sums January month data are in range **I305 to I309.**

*For  this in H316 write Date 01/01/2017 & apply the Cell Format "MMMM", like wise for February and others.*

Hope this help you.